# Why does audio.buffered.end(0) get an error message when I try to get buffered time

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I'm building mp3 playlist player with HTML5 and jQuery. At this player there is a horizontal bar grow gradually in conjunction with the buffered present of mp3 file.

here is my full code:
[get buffered end](http://jsfiddle.net/zuhairtaha/d9oj3dan/)

HTML5:

```
<audio id="music" controls>
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/musicTestAudio27/Very%20nice%20%2827%29.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
    <br/>
    <div id="buffered"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#buffered{
    border:solid #ccc 1px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    width:1%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var track = document.getElementById("music");
setInterval(function(){
var w = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;
$('#buffered').css("width",w+"%");
}, 1000);
```

but Firefox give me an error message said:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed
>   amount
>
> var w = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;

and Google chrome said:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The
>   index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that error is coming when accessing buffered.end before the element is initialized. 
you can rewrite that code as to avoid it

```
track = document.getElementById("music");
track.onprogress = function(){
    var w = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;
    $('#buffered').css("width",w+"%");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this was so helpful. I've been searching for four days. but now it's work like a charm ^_^ 

I added this:
**`    if(track.onprogress){
        var w2 = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;
        $('#buffered').css("width",w2+"%");
}`**

Answer (score 7):

```
track = document.getElementById("music");
track.onprogress = function(){
    if(track.buffered.length>0){
        var w = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;
        $('#buffered').css("width",w+"%");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code may be useful to you there is no explanation of what it does or why it answers the question or what it does that is different to the other answers. A good answer should include an explanation covering these topics.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - agreed. This code snippet was exactly what I needed, but it was only the context of the other answers that gave it meaning for me. I'd like to upvote but can't while the answer provided no explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer doesn't solve the problem for me. You also should check that the track has loaded before you access buffered.end like so:

```
track.onprogress = function(){
    if (track.readyState === 4){
        var w = 100*(track.buffered.end(0))/track.duration;
        $('#buffered').css("width",w+"%");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the audio element is not loaded yet, so there are no time ranges for the code to find so it returns an error.

Comment: How is this answer different from the already given ones (from 3 years ago ...)?