# Audio Buffering Produces 0 TimeRanges Until Fully Loaded

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an HTML5 audio player and I'm trying to monitor it's buffering progress until it reaches 100% so I can run it.

```js
music = document.querySelector("#music");
progress = document.querySelector("#progress");

music.addEventListener("progress", function(){
    var z = (music.buffered.end(0) / music.duration)*100;
    progress.value = z;
}, false);
```

*(Where `#progress` is an HTML `<progress>` element.)*

When I attempt the above code, I get this error.

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).

[This error has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651719/why-does-audio-buffered-end0-get-an-error-message-when-i-try-to-get-buffered-t), but the code I am using is similar to the code used in the answer, and I am still getting the error.

Here's the weird part: I monitored `music.buffered.length`, and it only reached `1` when the audio was fully loaded, so for some reason I cannot monitor the buffered length of my audio element.

[Here's a rather robust JS Bin to show the problem.](http://jsbin.com/roquhujuba/edit?js,console,output)

Has anyone else run into this problem? Am I doing something completely wrong here?

Comment: it likely depends on the server, but you can just use the 'canplaythrough' event

Comment: `canplaythrough` wouldn't solve the problem, I'm trying to create a loading bar of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get buffered value in `loadeddata` listener:

```
      audio.addEventListener ('loadeddata', function () {
        
        if (typeof (this.buffered) !== 'undefined' && this.buffered.length > 0) {
          
          audio.addEventListener ('progress', function () {
            
            var z = (this.buffered.end (0) / this.duration) * 100;
            progress.innerText = z;
            
          });
          
        }
        
      });
```

keep in mind that it inherits `this`, not `music`!

Comment: This is a very good answer, especially if you already know the size of your file.

Comment: @Orangestar thank you :) But we don't need to know the size of file (and it's nice), only `duration` field which is stored in ANY **correct** mp3, so it's a reason why do we need to use the `loadeddata` to obtain it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Years down the line, I managed to determine the problem. @dandavis was correct. My server was not supplying metadata about audio files, so the browser had no clue how long an audio file was (or even how big the file was in size) until it was completely downloaded. There was no timerange because there was no information about time supplied at all.

If you're having this problem, make sure your server is supplying EVERYTHING about your audio file.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to try and replace this part:

```
music.addEventListener("progress", function(){
    var z = (music.buffered.end(0) / music.duration)*100;
    progress.innerText = z;
}, false);
```

with this part:

```
if(music.onprogress){
    var z = (music.buffered.end(0) / music.duration)*100;
    progress.innerText = z;
};
```